# create a data backup application/software for windows

Tags: windows, backup

I wanted to make one for my project but I have no idea on how to begin. Can someone help me? This may be inappropriate but this is the only way I know to ask for help. Message me if you have idea please?

Answer (score 0):

There is an archived bit on the file attributes.  This is cleared if the file is modified, and you could set it when you archive a file

Comment: That point there is interesting, but my problem for now is the development itself. I don't really have an idea on how to implement the application and what are the tools to use to develop one. I'm still on the stage of planning the application development and everything is still vague.